# Get a sale rule coupons

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've got a Shopping Cart Price Rule with coupons and I need to retrieve these coupons in my code.

This is my Observer but it doesn't work :/

```
$promo = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(1);
$coupons = $promo->getCoupons();

foreach($coupons as $c)
{
    die($c);
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get all of the coupon codes you must get the collection:

```
$rulesCollection = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection();
foreach($rulesCollection as $rule){
    $coupon = $rule->getCode();
}
```

Magento 1.7 uses getCode() to get the coupon code.